# PHP intval() function returns different value in server

Tags: php

I am using PHP log function [log(number,base);] my base value is 2. in certain condition it will return a value -INF. Then i use the intval() function `[ intval(($value*100))/100; ]` to get integer value, but my problem is that, for the value **-INF** the function intval returns a value **-9.2233720368548E+16**, but i am expecting a value 
0 instead of that. This is happening only in server side. in my local Xampp server it working good. Need your help fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems with the little code you posted.

First of all you shouldn't rely on code that relies on some form of `-INF` but rather catch the case first (for example for a logarithm you know that log2($x) is -INF for $x = 0, so check for `intval($x) == 0`).

Second, you should probably rather use `round()` (if you want to have the rounding done by PHP) or `floor()` (if you want to go ahead with your `floor($x / 100) * 100` piece of code).

And thirdly, your problem most likely comes from the fact that the server is a 64-bit and your machine is a 32-bit system. But this is just the end of the chain. If you do things properly, you won't encounter the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to create a [`round()`](http://www.php.net/round) function, but why not use the in built one?

```
$number = round($number, 2);
```